# c++ Auto Increment Build Version By Time & Date

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i am trying to create Auto Increment Build Version By Time & Date

i couldnt add date & time in #define

version.h file

```
#define STRINGIZE2(s) #s
#define STRINGIZE(s) STRINGIZE2(s)


#define VERSION_MAJOR     5
#define VERSION_MINOR     0
#define VERSION_REVISION  2
#define VERSION_BUILD     1

#define PRODUCTVER         VERSION_MAJOR, VERSION_MINOR, VERSION_REVISION, VERSION_BUILD
#define STRFILEVER        STRINGIZE(VERSION_MAJOR)  "." STRINGIZE(VERSION_MINOR) "." STRINGIZE(VERSION_REVISION) "." STRINGIZE(VERSION_BUILD)
```

.rc file

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION PRODUCTVER
 PRODUCTVERSION PRODUCTVER

            VALUE "FileVersion", STRFILEVER
            VALUE "ProductVersion", STRFILEVER
```

i tried

```
#define VERSION_MAJOR     __DATE__
#define VERSION_MINOR      __TIME__
#define VERSION_REVISION  2
#define VERSION_BUILD     1
```

also  i tried other ways like

```
time_t now;
struct tm *current;
now = time(0);
current = localtime(&now);
    #define VERSION_MAJOR    current->tm_wday
    #define VERSION_MINOR      current->tm_hour
    #define VERSION_REVISION  2
#define VERSION_BUILD     1
```

nothing succeed

i just wanted to add day and hour in define

i hope there be a solution

Thank You

Comment: Let your build system do it (if you know what that actually means). Your last try made me smile. `<3` Taking a pause in programming and having some books or tutorials in C++ to read is highly recommended for you.

Comment: i already have a book for c++, but not everything in books, also i search on google and find other ways for build version, but i prefer this one

Comment: Indeed, books can't teach you everything. Though it will at least give a clue why your last variant fails to work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

Given the example below, we have a build script modify the value in the version text.

```
static const char   version_text[] = "519";
char const *
Version_Get_Text(void)
{
    return version_text;
}

unsigned int
Version_Text_Length(void)
{
    return sizeof(version_text) - 1U;
}
```

No need for messy `#define` macros.  The functions also preserve run-time and type safety:  None of the files accessing these functions need to be rebuilt when the version changes; only this module.

This technique, combined with our automated build server, has lasted us a year so far with no issues.

Also, no optimizations are necessary.  Accessing the version is not part of the core operations of our product; it only happens during initialization when the debug prompt is first displayed or when a User sends a command asking for the version.  In these cases, execution time is not critical.